# Использование ssh ключа с другой системы

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, rsa

Раньше у меня была установлена *убунту 18*, я сгенерировал на ней ssh ключи и закинул на *gitlab*, чтобы каждый раз не вводить пароль. Через какое-то время я поставил с 0 *убунту 20*, но перед этим я сохранил ключи на флешку. После установки новой системы я копировал ключи обратно в папку **~.ssh/**, однако гит уже не хочет работать через них и требует каждый раз вводить пароль.

Скажите, пожалуйста,я забыл что-то еще сохранить помимо **.ssh/** или как-то можно решить эту проблему без генерации новых ключей?

Comment: Правильные права доступа к приватному ключу, например?

Comment: @andreymal Да, все как здесь написано https://superuser.com/a/215506

Comment: так проверьте: `$ ssh -T пользователь@компьютер`. значения для `пользователь` и `компьютер` — ровно те же, что и в url вашего хранилища.

Comment: @Nobody, в приведённой вами ссылке полностью упущен ключевой момент о принадлежности каталога `~/.ssh` и его содержимого.